# Calculating cosine similarity in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, similarity, cosine-similarity

My dataset looks like this

```
rows = [("user1",1,2,10), 
        ("user2",2,6,27), 
        ("user3",3,3,21), 
        ("user4",4,7,44) 
      ]
columns = ["id","val1","val2","val3"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rows, schema = columns)
```

[image]

And I want to calculate cosine similarity scores for each user like below,

[image]

Kindly help in solving this.

Ps: I do not want to use sklearn library as I am dealing with big data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `UDF` function and a `pivot`:

```py
import numpy as np

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F, types as T

@F.udf(T.DoubleType())
def cos_sim(a, b):
    return float(np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b)))

# Columns representing the values of the vectors
vector_columns = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('val')]

df2 = (
    df.alias('a')
    .crossJoin(df.alias('b'))
    .withColumn(
        'cs',
        cos_sim(
            F.array(*[F.col(f'a.{c}') for c in vector_columns]),
            F.array(*[F.col(f'b.{c}') for c in vector_columns]),
        )
    )
    .groupby('a.id')
    .pivot('b.id')
    .sum('cs')
)
```

The result is:

```bash
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|   id|             user1|             user2|             user3|             user4|
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|user1|1.0000000000000002|0.9994487303346109|0.9975694083904585|0.9991881714548081|
|user2|0.9994487303346109|               1.0|0.9947592087399117|0.9980077882931742|
|user3|0.9975694083904585|0.9947592087399117|               1.0|0.9985781309458447|
|user4|0.9991881714548081|0.9980077882931742|0.9985781309458447|               1.0|
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Clearly, you can use a plain pyspark implementation. It depends on the quantity of data you have to process. Usually UDFs are slower, but simpler and faster to play with, especially when you want to try some quick thing.

Here a possible plain pyspark implementation:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import add


def mynorm(*cols):
    return F.sqrt(reduce(add, [F.pow(c, 2) for c in cols]))    
    
def mydot(a_cols, b_cols):
    return reduce(add, [a * b for a, b in zip(a_cols, b_cols)])


def cos_sim_ps(a_cols, b_cols):
    return mydot(a_cols, b_cols) / (mynorm(*a_cols) * mynorm(*b_cols))
    

df3 = (
    df.alias('a')
    .crossJoin(df.alias('b'))
    .withColumn(
        'cs',
        cos_sim_ps(
            [F.col(f'a.{c}') for c in vector_columns],
            [F.col(f'b.{c}') for c in vector_columns],
        )
    )
    .groupby('a.id')
    .pivot('b.id')
    .sum('cs')
)
```

Comment: good use of `np.dot` & `np.linalg.norm`. I've been looking for this type of usage. ++ for this.

Comment: If you prefer, you can also use the [`cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) function by `scipy`. To get the similarity and not the distance, you can use ```1 - cosine(x, y)```

Comment: We have solved a similar problem without use of UDF - just posted the solution. As we could not use UDF, we couldn't use numpy vector functions.

Comment: @PieCot I got the following error with this solution. "Detected implicit cartesian product for FULL OUTER JOIN".

Comment: I've updated the answer: please, see if the new version solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works but its too slow for a large dataset containing more than 70 million records.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do it for large amount of data. We had a requirement to compute cosine similarity for large number of entities and we compared multiple solutions. The `UDF` based solution was very slow as lot of data has to be broadcasted for each pairwise computation.

Following is another version of this implementation which scaled very well for us:

```py
data_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != "id"]
df_cos_sim = df.withColumn("others", F.array(*data_cols)).drop(*data_cols)
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.withColumnRenamed("others", "this").crossJoin(df_cos_sim)
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.withColumn("dot_prod", F.lit(sum([F.col("this")[i] * F.col("others")[i] for i in range(len(data_cols))])))
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.withColumn("norm_1", F.lit(F.sqrt(sum([F.col("this")[i] * F.col("this")[i] for i in range(len(data_cols))]))))
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.withColumn("norm_2", F.lit(F.sqrt(sum([F.col("others")[i] * F.col("others")[i] for i in range(len(data_cols))]))))
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.withColumn("cosine_similarity", F.lit(F.col("dot_prod") / (F.col("norm_1") * F.col("norm_2"))))
df_cos_sim = df_cos_sim.drop("this", "others", "dot_prod", "norm_1", "norm_2")
```

Output is pairwise cosine similarity:

```
+-----+-----+------------------+
|   id|   id| cosine_similarity|
+-----+-----+------------------+
|user1|user1|1.0000000000000002|
|user1|user2|0.9994487303346109|
|user1|user3|0.9975694083904585|
|user1|user4|0.9991881714548081|
|user2|user1|0.9994487303346109|
|user2|user2|               1.0|
|user2|user3|0.9947592087399117|
|user2|user4|0.9980077882931742|
|user3|user1|0.9975694083904585|
|user3|user2|0.9947592087399117|
|user3|user3|               1.0|
|user3|user4|0.9985781309458447|
|user4|user1|0.9991881714548081|
|user4|user2|0.9980077882931742|
|user4|user3|0.9985781309458447|
|user4|user4|               1.0|
+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting the **"Column is not iterable"** error on the 4th line of code.

Comment: what is the output of `df.columns`? You need to select only those columns in data_cols on which you want to compute cosine similarity.

Comment: ['val1','val2','val3'] is the output of the first line **data_cols**. The error occured in the 4th line when creating **"dot_prod"** column

Comment: Are you using the same dataframe as shared in the question? I can run with same source code.

Comment: It is the same data frame. Please help in correcting this error.

Comment: I can't analyse why you are getting this issue. It worked fine for me with the dataframe creation source code that you have shared. Try it in a fresh notebook with exact this source code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vyUFewk6x7v8XjxDdaX6fh9YPFGL86kn/view?usp=sharing   Attached is the error screenshot with the link. kindly advise.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/) and share the link with me?